# Example of an $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$- module

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a point $p$ on a variety $X$. Let $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ be the local ring of polynomials at $p$. In Algebraic geometry, we often study $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$- modules. Could I get an example of such a module? I used to mainly take $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ as a module over itself, but that seems to be a pretty unhelpful example. Thank you

Comment: Take any $\mathcal{O}_X$ module $M$, and consider the stalk $M_p$

Comment: Perhaps it was only a mistake, but just in case you're confused about this Ayush...we take $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ to be the local ring of germs of regular functions at $p$, *including* those that vanish at $p$.  In fact, the unique maximal ideal in $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ we call $m_{p}$ which consists of all germs of regular functions vanishing at $p$.  Quotienting by this maximal ideal gives you the underlying field.

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco- Thank you for the correction. Yes, it was a typing mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is pretty much *the* answer, but it's worth saying a few more things. For example, let $L$ be a line bundle/invertible sheaf on $X$. Then the stalk $L_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_{X,p}$ by definition, but is a module over it in a slightly more interesting way. More generally, for a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ the stalk at $p$ is an $\mathcal O_{X,p}$-module isomorphic to $\mathcal O_{X,p}^{\oplus r}$. Even more generally, for $\mathcal F$ a coherent sheaf, the stalk $\mathcal F_p$ is isomorphic to a finite direct sum power of $\mathcal O_{X,p}$, but the power can vary with $p$.